# Sign up works/password reset works but cannot sign in again once either are completed

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Quite new to B2C and have setup custom policies which did seem to be working ok.

Since adding the reset password functionality: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-password-reset-policy?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

I have found that local user accounts can sign up and it will sign them in but will not let them log in again.
Same happens for resetting the password. It all goes through the user can log in and then on next login it doesn't accept the creds.

B2C audit logs shows the password reset as a success... not sure what I am missing?

EDIT: I checked on another tenant I was testing on which I had not setup the password reset yet and have the same issue with local user account creation.

The only piece that is different to the examples is that I have multi-tenant azure AD idp setup.

Any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you did not complete the setup for the proxyief and ief app registrations correctly. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-user-flows?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#register-identity-experience-framework-applications

Delete your proxyief and ief app registrations, then use my tool to reprovision them: https://aka.ms/iefsetup

After reprovisioing, test after a few minutes.

It will overwrite your custom policy files, so download them back and setup the AAD multi tenant technical profile again afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did actually use your app initially but ran it again to no avail. 

Then realised I hadn't actually specified the above application ID's in the custom policy files. Stupid mistake but thanks for the help, pointed me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Application ID's needed to be added to the technical profile of trusedbaseextensions file for non interactive logins.

Application ID's for both app registrations mentioned.